# Random effects in repeated-measures design using lme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I have a repeated-measures design where participants were measured 4 times each on 2 consecutive days. There were 2 conditions, randomly attributed to day 1 and day 2 for each participant.

So, this is how the head of my data 'dat' look:

[image: So, this is how the head of my data 'dat' look:]

'subject' is just the IDs, 'DV' is my outcome/dependent variable.

I want to know how 'day', condition ('cond'), and 'measurement' influence 'DV' using R's lme package. Even after a rather excessive search, I'm still not sure how to set the random effects...

So far, I've done something like:

```
m_base <- lme(DV ~ 1, random = ~1|subject/cond/measurement, data = dat, method = "ML")
```

or

```
m_base <- lme(DV ~ 1, random = ~1|subject/day/measurement, data = dat, method = "ML")
```

and then stepwise added my variables as fixed effects using `update()` and compared the models using `anova()`.

Still, I'm **not sure about how to set the random effects**, since 'measurement' is somehow nested within both 'day' and 'cond'. Does anyone know a correct way of implementing my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that you have a case of a partially crossed, partially nested design, because if I understand correctly, `day` and `cond` are crossed (ie neither are nested in the other), while both appear to be nested within `subject`. `measurement` is an id variable that indexes the measurement occasion on each day and within each condition, and as such should not be treated as a random factor because there is only one observation of the dependent variable for each measurement occasion. Even though they are indexed as 1-4 for each day/condition, they are different measurements (that is, measurement 1 for day 1 condition 0 and measurement 1 for day 1 condition 1 are not the same measurement) and therefore there can be no random variation in it. If you specified it as random in the way you have coded the data above, it would be a mistake.

If this is the case, then `lme` is unable to fit such a model, and you could use something like `lme4` instead. You could specify the structure in `lme4` as follows:

```
DV ~ 1 + (1|subject) + (1|day) + (1|cond) + (1|subject:day) + (1|subject:cond)
```

If `measurement` is a measurement of time within each `day` or `cond` and you expect some temporal effect, then you could include `measurement` as a fixed effect (and also potentially fit random slopes, if the data supported such a model)

*However*, fitting a model with random intercepts for `day` and `cond` would not be a good idea because you have only 2 of each, so you would be asking the software to estimate a variance for a normally distributed variable having only 2 observations, which does not make any sense. So a better way forward is to treat `day` and `cond` as fixed effects, and simply fit random intercepts for `subject`:

```
DV ~ day + cond + (1|subject)
```

The fact that `day` and `cond` were randomly assigned is not relevant.

The same comment as above applies for `measurement` again here. That is, you might want to fit

```
DV ~ day + cond + measurement + (1|subject)
```

and again, you could also have random slopes for `day` and/or `cond` and/or `measurement` if suggested by the domain theory and supported by the data.

Of course, now that we have discarded `day` and `cond` as random, you can go back to the `nlme` package if you wish (athough `lme4` is really the successor to `nlme` for most cases)

Comment: The use of fixed effects because only 2 obs/factor makes sense to me, but doesn't this present a problem because day and condition are completely confounded within each subject?  I'm looking at the `DV ~ day + cond + (1|subject)` line.

Comment: @MichiganWater what do you mean by "completely confounded within each subject", and in what sense does it present a problem for fixed effects estimation ? In this type of situation I would usually run a bunch of simulations of data based on the experimental design, and check that I get sensible results from the model(s). I can't honestly remember if I did that when I answered this question, as it's a while ago now.

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to explain it, so I'll just use an example of the first subject ID01.  There'll be a difference calculated between the first 4 measurements and the second 4 measurements, but there's no way to attribute that difference to either 'day' or 'cond' because they are perfectly correlated.  Looking across subjects, sometimes cond=0 occurs on day=1 and sometimes on day=2, but there's no way to break that correlation within a subject.  I simulated a bit and got _fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient_

Comment: @MichiganWater OK I see what you mean. Without delving into this question again I can't really say much more. In principal there shouldn't be a problem but if the fixed effects model matrix is singular that points to a problem with the experimental design or maybe an issue with missing data. We were never given the whole dataset so it's possible there are other measurements for the IDs in the extract. Maybe the OP can comment (though they haven't been seen for over a month). Or if you wanted to ask a questiion with some simulated data, I could take a look. Feel free to ping me here if you do.